# Can we handle tableview didSelect delegate or UIButton Action inside IntentViewController?

Tags: ios12, sirishortcuts

I want to handle table view didSelectAtRow delegate method in Siri Shortcuts Custom IntentUI.

Also I wan to handle UIButton Action in Siri Shortcuts Custom IntentUI.

Is any of the case possible?

Please share some solution (if possible)

```
#SiriShortcuts 
#iOS12 
#Custom IntentUI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't handle interactions in a Custom Intent UI as the intent controller does not receive touch interactions. This is from the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_ui_extension/configuring_the_view_controller_for_your_custom_interface) -> Check the section requirements and limitations.

`You can update your view controllers as needed using timers or other programmatic means. Your view controllers also receive the normal callbacks when they are loaded, shown, and hidden. However, your view controllers do not receive touch events or any other events while they are onscreen, and you cannot add gesture recognizers to them. Therefore, never create an interface with controls or views that require user interactions.`